# How to make my doubly Linked list printBackward() Function Print all numbers on C++?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I studied about Doubly Linked list and got stuck on how to make my "PrintBackward" Function print all number

The input is 1 2 3
The Output I want is 3 2 1

But my Output now is resulted on 3 2 only

Here's my code. Can anyone tell me what causes this problem and a hint for Solution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

void printList(Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void printBackward(Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->prev;
    }
}


void push(Node** head_ref,Node** tail_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();

    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);   
    new_node->prev = *tail_ref;
    
    //update first node to point to newnode
    if(*head_ref != NULL){
        (*head_ref)->prev = new_node;
    }
    
    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
    
    /*5. update tail for the first node*/
    if(*tail_ref == NULL){
        *tail_ref = new_node;
    }
    }
    
void appendTail(Node** head_ref,Node** tail_ref , int new_data)
{
    
    // 1. allocate node
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    
    // 2. Put in the data
    new_node->data = new_data;
    
    // 3. This new node is going to be
    // the last node, so make next of
    // it as NULL
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = *tail_ref;
    
    // 4. If the Linked List is empty,
    // then make the new node as head
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }
    
    // 6. Change the next of last node
    if(*tail_ref != NULL){
        (*tail_ref)->next = new_node;
    }
    *tail_ref = new_node;
    return;
}

    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
    
    appendTail(&head, &tail, 1);    
    appendTail(&head, &tail, 2);
    appendTail(&head, &tail, 3);
    printBackward(tail);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I tried using AppendTail to add the numbers to make a list of 1 2 3
I want to make it print out in backward like 3 2 1
Maybe I forget to link one list? The list won't print out the one with NULL on the head or something? I tried find the solution everywhere and now I'm totally strucked.

Comment: How would you do it forward? Backward in a doubly linked list sn't all that different really. In fact it is one of the reasons for doubly linked lists to exist

Comment: Did you try `printList(head)`? If that gives you `2 3` (or really anything other than `1 2 3`), then you have a strong indicator that you should be looking at (and asking about) `appendTail()` rather than `PrintBackward()`. Walk through that function assuming an empty list, and make sure it does what you want it to do.

Comment: Wow.. I just realized. the PrintList also make an output to only 1 on there! I just saw a new problem... maybe I should fix that first..

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: anything other than `1 2 3` **or `1 2`** would be a strong indicator that you should look at `appendTail`. Getting `1 2` would suggest that your printing algorithm is dropping the last node, regardless of direction. Not the case here, but just in case someone uses this information in the future...

Comment: Looks like `appendTail` doesn't update the tail when the list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. But more important are the problems with the design.

Strictly spoken, you do not have a linked list. There is no object "list" or similar that could be instantiated. You have only "nodes" that you try link with external functions.

Look at the interface of [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Then you interstand what I mean.

Then, in your "appendTail", you do not handle the pointer correctly. Especially, if you add the fist node. There you just set the head pointer and not the tail pointer. That is wrong. And all following tries to add something to the list, will fail.

If you have 1 element in the list. Then head and tail pointer must point to the same element.

In your case the links are broken.

After adding 1,2 and 3 the pointers will look like:
[image]

You see, you need to redesign your push and appenTail functions. Or better, the complete design . . .

And then refactor your code.

By the way. Standard implementations of a doubly linked list use a node as a sentinel. "next" and "previous" pointers in this node are used as head and tail pointers. This makes navigation much more simply. There is no need to differentiate the special cases of handling the start and tail node.

And travisering is usually done with iterators.

You may study the following example of a doubly link list

```
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a header file -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Type trait helper to identify iterators --------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// The List class ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class List {
    // Sub class for a Node -----------
    struct Node {
        T data{};
        Node* next{};
        Node* previous{};
        Node() {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p) : next(n), previous(p) {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p, const T& d) : next(n), previous(p), data(d) {}
    };

    // Private list data and functions --------
    Node* head{};
    size_t numberOfElements{};
    void init() { head = new Node(); head->next = head; head->previous = head; numberOfElements = 0; }

public:
    struct iterator;    // Forward declaration

    // Constructor --------------------
    List() { init(); }
    explicit List(const size_t count) { init(); insert(begin(), count); }
    explicit List(const size_t count, const T& value) { init(); insert(begin(), count, value); };
    template <typename Iter>
    List(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { init(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    List(const List& other) { init(), insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); };

    List(List&& other) : head(other.head), numberOfElements(other.numberOfElements) { other.init(); }
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { init(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <int N> List(T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }
    template <int N> List(const T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }


    // Assignment ---------------------
    List& operator =(const List& other) { clear(); insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); return *this; }
    List& operator =(List&& other) { clear(); head = other.head; numberOfElements = other.numberOfElements; other.init(); return *this; }
    List& operator =(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    template <typename Iter> void assign(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { clear(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    template <int N> void assign(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> void assign(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    void assign(const size_t count, const T& value) { clear(); insert(begin(), count, value); }
    void assign(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }

    // Destructor ---------------------
    ~List() { clear(); delete head; }

    // Element Access -----------------
    T& front() { return *begin(); }
    T& back() { return *(--end()); }

    // Iterators ----------------------
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head->next, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(head, head); }

    // Capacity -----------------------
    size_t size() const { return numberOfElements; }
    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    // Modifiers ----------------------
    void clear();

    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition);
    template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool> = true>
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il);

    iterator erase(const iterator& posToDelete);
    iterator erase(const iterator& first, const iterator& last);

    void pop_front() { erase(begin()); };
    void push_front(const T& d) { insert(begin(), d); }

    void pop_back() { erase(--end()); };
    void push_back(const T& d) { insert(end(), d); }

    void resize(size_t count, const T& value);
    void resize(size_t count);

    void swap(List& other) { std::swap(head, other.head); std::swap(numberOfElements, other.numberOfElements); }

    // Operations --------------------
    void reverse();

    // Non standard inefficient functions --------------------------
    T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return begin()[index]; }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define iterator capability ---------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {

        // Definitions ----------------
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Data -----------------------
        Node* iter{};
        Node* head{};

        // Constructor ----------------
        iterator(Node* const node, Node* const h) : iter(node), head(h) {};
        iterator() {};

        // Dereferencing --------------
        reference operator*() const { return iter->data; }
        reference operator->() const { return &**this; }

        // Arithmetic operations ------
        iterator operator++() { iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator--() { iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++* this; return tmp; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator tmp = *this; --* this; return tmp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };
        // Comparison ----------------- (typical space ship implementation)
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; };
        bool operator !=(const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; };
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter < 0; };
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter <= 0; };
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter > 0; };
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter >= 0; };

        // Special non standard functions -----------------
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const;
        reference operator[] (const size_t index);
    };
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of list functions. This would normally go into a TCC file -----------------------

// List class functions ---------------
template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {

    for (Node* nextNode{}, * currentNode(head->next); currentNode != head; currentNode = nextNode) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
    }
    delete head;
    init();
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous, value);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}

template <typename T>
template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool>>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last) {
    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (first != last) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, *first);
        Iter i(first);
        for (++i; i != last; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, *i);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value) {

    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (count != 0u) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
        for (size_t i{ 1u }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il) {
    return insert(insertBeforePosition, il.begin(), il.end());
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& posToDelete) {

    iterator result = posToDelete;
    ++result;

    Node* nodeToDelete = posToDelete.iter;

    if (nodeToDelete != head) {

        nodeToDelete->previous->next = nodeToDelete->next;
        nodeToDelete->next->previous = nodeToDelete->previous;

        delete nodeToDelete;
        --numberOfElements;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& first, const List<T>::iterator& last) {
    iterator result{ end() };
    if (first == begin() && last == end())
        clear();
    else {
        while (first != last)
            first = erase(first);
        result = last;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end());
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count, const T& value) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end(), value);
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
    const Node* oldHead = head;

    for (Node* nptr = head; ; nptr = nptr->previous) {
        std::swap(nptr->next, nptr->previous);
        if (nptr->previous == oldHead) // Previous was the original next
            break;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Iterator functions -----------------
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::difference_type List<T>::iterator::operator-(const iterator& other) const {

    difference_type result{};
    Node* nptr = head;

    int indexThis{ -1 }, indexOther{ -1 }, index{};

    do {
        nptr = nptr->next;
        if (nptr == iter)
            indexThis = index;
        if (nptr == other.iter)
            indexOther = index;
        ++index;
    } while (nptr != head);

    if (indexThis >= 0 and indexOther >= 0)
        result = indexThis - indexOther;
    return result;
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::reference List<T>::iterator::operator[] (const size_t index) {
    Node* nptr = head->next;
    for (size_t i{}; i < index and nptr != head; ++i, nptr = nptr->next)
        ;
    return nptr->data;
}
int main() {
    List<int> list{ 1,2,3 };
    for (const int i : list)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    List<int>::iterator iter = list.begin();
    std::cout << '\n' << iter[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wow!! I’ll study it! I didn’t change things much in this code because 1. This is the code that my professor teach my class. I can’t really change them but he left code at this state and I feel like I’m left on a deserted island in the middle of the sea and 2. I didn’t learn C++ from the start so I really don’t know what to do. I just found a solution myself yesterday yet I don’t understand how it works so I didn’t commented here. Thank you for leading me a way!